# Latin phrases - used in French too?

Tags: usage, expressions, choix-de-mot, latin

There are lots of latin phrases in common use in English. Is it suitable/appropriate/common to directly use them in French, exactly like I would for English?

For the purposes of discussion lets look at a few specific examples, rather than the general case:

- Ad hoc
- Vice versa
- de jure/de facto
- bona fide

Par exemple: « Sa carte d'identité est bona fide »

Comment: See http://www.abnihilo.com and the pink pages in the middle of a French dictionary.

Comment: @Raphink - thanks for the link, my dictionary didn't seem to have anything useful to say on Latin that I could see.

Comment: Far from a *constructive* comment to this interesting question, but it bears mentioning that there has been a dramatic evolution in French writing (/writers) between pre-XXth-century era and our days: pick up any XIXth century book (including fairly "popular" novels of the times) and you will notice an abundance of latin locutions (common and less common ones). This practice has progressively shifted from "normal" to "pedant"/"precious" to "plain old quaint" over the past 100 years or so (along with the progressive disappearance of latin from regular school curricula).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ça dépend. La réponse est forcément ad hoc.

« [Ad hoc](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ad%20hoc) » est souvent considéré comme francisé. Le Trésor de la langue française la liste comme locution latine, mais ne la met pas en italiques, c'est donc un mot fortement intégré (pas complètement, puisqu'il s'écrit en deux mots reste invariable même comme adjectif). Ce n'est pas un mot très courant, mais la plupart des locuteurs natifs le comprennent.

« [Vice versa](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/vice-versa) » (qui peut aussi s'écrire « vice-versa ») est pleinement intégré à part pour la prononciation (on prononce toujours « vicé versa » même si on n'écrit jamais l'accent). Le mot est tout à fait compréhensible et peut s'utiliser à l'écrit comme à l'oral.

« *De jure* » et « *de facto* » sont compréhensibles par un public cultivé, mais ne sont pas considérées comme du français (elles n'ont même pas d'entrée dans le TLF). En français, on dit « de droit » et « de fait ».

« *Bona fide* » n'existe pas en français et ne sera compris que par quelqu'un qui parle aussi anglais ou latin. En français, on dit « de bonne foi », « sincère ».

En règle générale, le français a eu un peu plus tendance à traduire les locutions latines que l'anglais : « c'est-à-dire » (abrégé c.à.d.) pour « *id est* » (i.e.), « par exemple » (par ex. ou p.e.) pour « *exempli gratia* » (e.g.), « CQFD » (ce qu'il fallait démontrer) pour « *QED* » (dans ces trois cas, l'expression ou l'abrévitation latine ne sera pas comprise par la plupart des français). Je pense que c'est parce qu'il y a eu plus tôt des textes scientifiques et juridiques en français qu'en anglais. De la même manière, les principes juridiques sont traduits en français (qui peut faire vieilli pour un non-juriste). Il y a quand même quelques exceptions comme « [etc](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/etc) », « [ipso facto](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ipso%20facto) ».

Comment: Je rajoute "pro bono", qui était peu utilisé auparavant et qui maintenant l'est beaucoup plus, par exemple chez les consultants (en plus des avocats).

Comment: @Sylvain Peyronnet: ... et chez les fans de U2.

Comment: @Laurent Tout à fait ;)

Comment: J'abrévierais « c.-à-d. », pour ma part.

Comment: Je rajouterais « et al. » aussi

Answer (score 5):

There are certain differences between Latin expressions used in English and in French. For example, `e.g.` or `bona fide` are not frequently used (I don't know the last one actually). `Vice versa` is mistakenly transformed into `Vice et versa`[(with a famous example)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TcE8N-EOcg), and so on... It is difficult to make a general statement for each one, as they evolve in their own way inside the language.

Some professions may used more Latin expressions than others too. You won't see much in Computer Science for example, but many in Law or in Literature.

Comment: `Vice et versa` should not be used in this written form. It's just a derivation due to the real pronunciation of `vice versa`.

Comment: True, it's not formerly written this way.

Comment: [Actually](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3354), you could see many in Computer Science for it's lexicon is very English-driven.

Answer (score 3):

I regularly use them when writing.

- e.g. *exampli gratia*
- i.e. *id est*
- *a priori* / *a posteriori* even if a French version exists (à priori)
- *et caetera* / *etc* / *et cetera desunt*
  _ *et al.* / *et alii* in bibliographies

Lot of those terms are used for the law, or some technical papers : "C'est devenu le standard *de facto*".

Sometimes I use some in oral expressions, "Il va se faire virer de là *manu militari*"

Comment: E.g. and i.e. are not used in French. De facto is not used much, « standard de fait » is the *standard de fait*.

Comment: Hmm, "à priori" is faulty in French, it must be spelled "a priori" just like in latin.

Comment: @Gilles: 'e.g.' is rare (but correct and occasionally found) in French, 'i.e.' is very common in scientific contexts (including high school-level maths). I feel *de facto* is quite common too, but can't really back this up by any hard proof.

Comment: @Dave *E.g.* is in neither the Petit Robert nor in the TLF. *I.e.* is mentioned (as a 1598 borrowing from English!) in the Petit Robert, but not in the TLF. I don't think I'd heard of either before learning English, and I wouldn't use them in a mathematical text in French (in France, maybe it's different in other countries). I question that they would be understood by even a technical audience. *De facto/de jure* are a little better known, they're in the Petit Robert but not in the TLF.

Comment: @Gilles: can't really find anything to back me up on 'e.g.' beside personal experience, so won't defend it. ;-) But I am more than positive that 'i.e.' is standard use (in Science and particularly Math) in France.

Comment: @Gilles: difficile de prouver un usage qui est fait avant tout en salle de classe et en amphi, mais je pense que [cette discussion](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?2,14403) donne une bonne idée du fait que 'i.e.' existe dans un tel contexte (même si apparemment il n'est pas toujours bien compris)...

Answer (score 2):

The use of Latin phrases are common, but it's formal.

Comment: or pedantic, depending on the context.