# How to translate “actually” in its contrastive meaning?

Tags: traduction, anglais

The sentence I can think it coming from would be “I'll stop … and **actually** do this.”

I fail to content myself with “*en fait*” or “*vraiment*”, for the former merely translates “as a matter of fact”, but isn't even very strong semantically (mostly used as punctuation, that is) ; and the latter is hardly contrastive at all (would well translate “really”, only that's not what I'm looking for).

Searching for it, I found [this topic on EL&U (“Actually” vs “really”)](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59540/26839), which looks like the sense I wanna convey:

> **actually**@Merriam-Webster: […]
>   2 : in point of fact — used to suggest something unexpected

<sub>I think [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/revisions/1453/13) is still valid, only it could be enriched.</sub>

---

La phrase qui m'y fait penser serait « Je vais arrêter de [tourner autour du pot, mettons], et *actually* [faire quelque chose] ». (En vrai, j'ai traduit par « [faire queque chose] *pour vrai* », mais j'espère qu'il y a des traductions plus correctes et moins régionales.)

« En fait » ou « vraiment » peinent à me contenter, parce que l'opposition entre ce qui est attendu et ce qui est *vraiment* fait n'est pas vraiment rendue, en fait. D'ailleurs, *en fait* sert davantage de ponctuation que d'articulation logique, chez moi.

Voir la version anglaise ci-avant¹ pour une description des nuances d'*actually*.

<sub>1 : *supra*, si c'est plus clair…</sub>

Comment: What about "au final"?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon : Pas très contrastif, si ?

Comment: "au final" transmet l'idée d'un dénouement différent (en mieux ou en pire) de ce qui était espéré initialement. Mais je ne sais pas si c'est que vous voulez dire par "contrastif".

Comment: Je vois de la continuité dans *au final*, qui introduit la suite de ce qui précédait. Au contraire, je cherche le sens d'*actually* qui sert à introduire quelque chose d'**innatendu** (***unexpected***). (Au fait, [on peut se tutoyer, peut-être](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie).)

Comment: *J'étais persuadé que c'était la femme de chambre dans le salon avec le chandelier, mais au final, c'était le majordome dans la bibliothèque avec le pistolet*.

Comment: Il me semble que tu a exclu *en fait* un peu vite. Il peut avoir un sens de contraste très fort, plus qu'une simple poncutation, ça dépend essentiellement de l'intonation. En revanche, pour ton exemple spécifique, je ne le trouve pas tout-à-fait idéal, c'est vrai.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: Oui : bien vu et oui : d'où ma question.
Au final, on dirait qu'*en fait* traduit généralement ce que je veux dire, mais que dans ce cas-ci, ça ne marche pas bien. Il y a peut-être moyen de retourner la phrase pour qu'*en fait* marche, genre *En fait, je vais arrêter de tourner autour du pot et faire quelque chose.* 
Si quelqu'un veut tourner ça en réponse.. (trouver d'autres exemples, peut-être ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faut pas rêver, une traduction exacte c'est pas possible. Dans cette phrase, je pense que ça peut se traduire approximativement comme ça :

> Je m’arrête là, et pour le coup je vais le faire.

Comment: Bonne idée, vraiment.

Comment: J'accepte cette (au demeurant excellente) réponse faute de mieux, mais si quelqu'un a une autre idée, dans un registre de langue moins trivial, par exemple, il est le très bienvenu à essayer de voler la coche verte.

Answer (score 1):

Je vais arrêter de tourner autour du pot, et *effectivement* faire quelque chose.

Comment: C'est proche de *vraiment* (*en effet*, même), mais du coup le contraste entre le début et la fin n'est pas très marqué... je trouve. Si c'est fait effectivement, ça ne peut pas être *unexpected*, comme dit Merriam-Webster : effectivement suppose qu'on y pensait déjà avant.

Answer (score 1):

In the context I think "plutôt" is a good translation.
Je vais arrêter de compter sur les autres, et je vais plutôt m'en occuper personnellement.

Comment: Mais là pour le coup ça ne veut plus dire "de fait", seulement "à la place". Avec mon exemple ça donnerait : *Je vais arrêter de tourner autour du pot et plutôt faire quelque chose.*, ça n'est pas le sens que je recherchais.